# Oracle Apex: Reset button not clearing validation message

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

Problem: I facing problem with reset button in form.
Scenario: There is around 3 validations are there which is happening at the time of submit the page. On submit click, validation occurs if data entered is not correct. While pressing reset button,ideally it should reset all the inputted fields as well as validation message from screen. But in my case, values got reset not validation messages. 
Could anyone please provide any solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to clear out validation message,
i created dynamic action which will execute java code and clear out validation message.
    apex.message.clearErrors();